# Usage of subprocess to run a LUA script

Tags: python-3.x, lua

When I use `os.system` in my python script the following LUA command runs.  The script does not wait for this LUA process to finish though.

```
os.system("cd ~/code/CNNMRF; qlua cnnmrf.lua -max_size 750  -content_name test -style_name style_img")
```

My understanding is that I need to use `subprocess`.  How would I map this `os.system` command to `subprocess`?

When I look at the examples I see `subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])` but I'm not sure how to modify this for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

os.system runs process. `cd ... ;` is a shell command.

What you need is `subprocess.run(["lua", "cnnmrf.lua" ...], shell=True, cwd='/home/<your user>/code/CNNMRF');`

In subprocess.call you can pass current work directory. There you cannot use `~`. You need to pass regular path with /home/.../code/CNNMRF

Arguments of `subprocess.run` - is list. So you need to split your command by spaces.